# Cleaner way to get form parameters in ASP.NET Core MVC Web App?

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core-mvc

I've got a web app for a form in which we collect a lot of information from the user from a single form, what's the best way to collect all this data without having `[FromForm] type variableName` 30 times in my parameter list?

Comment: Just use a single model that encapsulates all the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not using the action results and models that are able to transform your requests directly to a model, The MVC controller provides a list of keys vai this.Request.Form.Keys and you can loop over these keys.